# How to parse" Thanks a lot"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> ***Thanks*** a lot.

Is "Thanks" a verb or a noun? If it is a noun, how can "a lot" behind it modify "thanks"? If it is a verb, why is there an "s" at the end of the word?

Comment: Compare to "Greetings and salutations!"

Comment: I'd note that _thanks a lot_ is commonly used sarcastically to mean "no thanks at all" when someone has been distinctly less than helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a **performative exclamation**.  By uttering the word, you're not just *describing* the action of thanking, you're actually *performing* the action of thanking.  There are a number of words and phrases like this; for example, you can welcome someone simply by saying the word "Welcome!"

So why the peculiar grammar?  Well, take a look at its history:

> 1. I thank you.
> 2. Thank you.
> 3. Thanks.

The first sentence is a complete clause.  And as it became a single lexical item, it got shortened to the second form.  But the third form doesn't look like "thank you" at all, does it?

In fact, the third form was **reanalyzed** as a shortened form of "thank you".  It appears to instead be an exclamation derived from the plural noun "thanks", most likely short for a sentence like "Thanks be to you".  But in this case it's not used as though it's a short version of that phrase, and it's not used like a noun either.  Instead, it's used exactly like "thank you" grammatically:

> 1. I thank you **a lot**.
> 2. Thank you **a lot**.
> 3. Thanks **a lot**.

So "thanks", by appearances a noun, is standing in for the exclamation "thank you", which is historically a short form of the complete clause "I thank you".

Comment: Interesting!! I'd never heard *performative exclamation* before. Interestingly, your last 3 examples don't all read the same to me. *Thank you a lot* sounds odd but is perfectly understandable (I think it probably just sounds odd because *Thanks a lot* is so common). But to my ear, *I thank you a lot* means *On many occasions I have cause to thank you (and I do so)*. (It also just occurred to me that if the phrase had been "[x] very much" instead of "[x] a lot", version 2 would sound more natural to me, and 3 would sound odd! Interesting how we pair words sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed @Snailboat but I'm typing what found something interesting here on my 'Pro' version of WW.

The word *thanks* is a **noun and interjection both.** 'Thank' is verb. But when you say *thanks a lot* it shows as an interjection on WordWeb. It's interesting.

> The meaning of the **word** '[thanks (n, inter) and 'thank (v)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=thanks)'.
>
> The meaning of the **phrase** '[thanks a lot (inter)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=thanks%20a%20lot)', which means *emphasized thank you* **or** *an ironic* thank you.