# Thanks/Thank you for coming here

Tags: word-choice

What is the Word classes (or parts of speech) of the following words? and what is the clause elements of them?

> - **Thank** you for coming here ...
> - **Thanks** you for coming here ...

I think both of *thank* and *thanks* are verbs and the subject is omitted.

> - (I) Thank you for coming here ...
> - (John: the name of the person I'm talking with) Thanks you for coming here ...

I'm not sure about it. but If I'm right regards the above, so we cant't use thanks with plurals, Is it correct?

> (guys) <strike>thanks</strike> thank you coming here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Thank* is a verb, as you say, and the subject (I, we, they) is understood.

*Thanks* is a noun, but also an interjection.

So you can't say

> <s>Thanks you!</s>

although

> he/she thanks you

is fine and

> Thanks!

is also fine by itself.

See: [How to parse" Thanks a lot"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13595/how-to-parse-thanks-a-lot)

Comment: Thank you, but it is commonly used. event there is books titles use it "Thanks for the Memories" https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2410506.Thanks_for_the_Memories?

Comment: @Shannak  As I say, *thanks* (shorthand for *thank you*) is fine by itself. It's less formal and more likely to be used between friends and among families.

Comment: @Shannak Yes, that's *thanks* on its own. Although 'thank you' has become established, you can think of it as an abbreviated version of '**I** thank you', where the pronoun 'I' requires plural agreement.

Comment: @Shannak You may need a comma, "thanks, for the memories".

Comment: @Lawrence No, it never makes sense to say *I* takes plural agreement.  English has a third person singular affix *-s* (*he/she thank**s***), but the reason this affix is not used when the subject is *I* is because it isn't third person singular.  *I* is of course first person singular.

Comment: @snailplane That's a very interesting way of putting it. I agree that "I" isn't plural, of course :).